# Strange ListView dividers behaviour

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've been having some problems with the ListView divider.

As you can see, in the first picture [(Image 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PXRM.jpg), the divider is "thicker" or "darker" than in the second one [(Image2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sppCL.jpg).

The Image 1 happens whenever the fragment the ListView is in, is commited (via replace).

Then, when I click on an item, and the press the back button (poping the transaction from the backstack), the dividers are like in the second picture.

One thing to note is that if I click on an item in the first picture, where the dividers are darker, the color of the selection is yellow, whereas if I click being in the second picture, the selection is blue.

When I first created de app, it would always be like in the second picture, and that's how I want it to be.

I haven't found anything on the Internet... Why is this happening?
Maybe is has to do with the adapter? Thanks in advance.

ListView:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/notification_list"
    />
```

Method used to set the fragment where the ListView is:

```
 private void changeToFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    if (menuIsOpened)
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations( R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out, R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    if (addToBackStack)
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("menuOptionSelected");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

Invokation of this method:

```
changeToFragment (new NotificationsFragment(), false);
```

Notifications Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_notifications, container, false);

    // The ListView that will display the norifications
    final ListView notificationList = (ListView)         rootView.findViewById(R.id.notification_list);

    // We create and fill the adapter with the notifications and set it to the ListView
    notifications = NotificationBuilder.getNotifications();
    listAdapter = new NotificationAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.notification_layout, notifications);
    notificationList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

     ...some code...

    return rootView;
}
```

Adapter getView method:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        EduCloudNotification notification = notifications.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_layout, null);
        }
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notification_title);
        title.setText(notification.getTitle());

        TextView description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notification_description);
        description.setText(notification.getDescription());

        ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notification_icon);
        icon.setImageResource(notification.getIconId());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Where have you set the divider?

Comment: Something is causing the wrong theme to be applied. Try changing the `inflate()` call in your adapter to `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_layout, viewGroup, false)`

Comment: user2520215 I haven't set the divider anywhere.
@Brucelet I tried changing that but nothing has changed :/